# How to use PDFMarkedContentExtractor class from pdfbox library?

Tags: pdfbox

I use pdfbox library to extract text from arbitrary PDF file. And I want to know how can I extract some particular text from pdf using this library.

As I understand, I should use marked content feature for this task.
There is the [`PDFMarkedContentExtractor`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFMarkedContentExtractor.html) class. Using its `getMarkedContent` method I can get `PDMarkedContent` object, and then, by using method `getContents`, I can get a real content that I need.
Am I right?

Well, but how can I specify what the document `PDFMarkedContentExtractor` should use as a source?

Comment: Are you sure your source PDF files *do* contain marked content useful for your task? If you are not sure, please share a sample file.

Comment: I examined several files in [iTextRump](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups), and they have /MarkedInfo = True. Also, I can see StructureTreeRoot element. But I don't now how to use theses elements to specify the desired element for some text extractor. For example, I tried to use [this file](http://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Taking-Tagged-PDF-To-The-Next-Level.pdf).

Comment: You said you wanted to *extract page content without footnotes and other useless info*. Unfortunately I don't see many footnotes in your sample document. Do you have a serious sample file you'd really want to extract text from without footnotes etc.? Or do you really refer to arbitrary PDF files?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous description. I meant there is no special document that I want to extract text from. I want to know how to extract text from different documents. Actually, extracting text without footnotes is only one of the task. Another one is extracting text from the desired paragraph or section. So, you can try [this one](http://download.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/intel_ssd_toolbox_user_guide.pdf). But as I said, I want to be able do it with arbitrary PDF file.

Comment: *I meant there is no special document that I want to extract text from* - if you have no guarantees in excess of that the files are PDF files, trying to make use of tags is leading you nowhere due to the differing generation of tagging information.

Comment: Ok, sorry that I don't answer for so long. I've been trying to understand PDF structure better. So, you say: _trying to make use of tags is leading you nowhere due to the differing generation of tagging information_. But can't we use the RoleMap property of the PDStructureTreeRoot to match tags with standard ones some how?

Comment: What I meant is that it won't help you much to concentrate on the interpretation of tags if you want to extract text from arbitrary PDF documents, i.e. documents which most often *don't have tags.* In such a situation you should first search a solution getting along without tags. As soon as you have that, you can consider improving the solution for special cases, e.g. tagged PDFs. And that is when one may fight with different understandings of tagging by different PDF producers.

Comment: I understand that most of PDF files don't have tags. But I don't consider about them. I think that if PDF file is not tagged, we can extract text only from the desired page. There is no possibility to do it more accuracy. But if a PDF file is tagged, How can I use PDFMarkedContentExtractor or other appropriate class to extract tagged text?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, PDFMarkedContentExtract is used specifically for tagged contents within the PDF.  Based upon your comments and your description, I believe you just want to extract the text in general.  If that's the case, I believe you need to use PDFTextStripper instead.